# PHP: How to encode HTML smartly

Tags: php, tcpdf, html-encode

while using tcpdf.writeHTML() I met the following problem:

I need to enter valid HTML into the function, but I get the text from non-valid-DB-fields

e.g: (in the following, I added space within the tags and entities so one can see them...)

```
$htmlFreeText .= '• Capacité : jusqu'à 10 kg <br >'; // err! 
$htmlFreeText .= '• Température : <75% RH <br >';    // err!
```

if I manually replace into HTML entities all works well:

```
$htmlFreeText .= '• Capacité : jusqu & #039 ; à 10 kg < br >'; // works!
$htmlFreeText .= '• Température : & lt ; 75% RH < br >'; // works!
```

I tried using `htmlspecialchars($myString, ENT_QUOTES, 'ISO-8859-1', true);`
but I need to keep the following HTML tags and not replace it into & lt ; tag & gt ;

```
<br >      
<strong > </strong>      
<b> </b>      
<i> </i>      
<u> </u>      
<sup> </sup>
<a href="http://www.lien.com" >titre ici</a>    
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.lien.com" >titre ici</a>
```

I can replace almost all these tags into {opening-tag} {/closing-tag}
use htmlspecialchars, and then replace back all {tags} into < tags >
but in this solution I have a problem with < a > opening tag.

Is there a simple PHP function I can use that keeps HTML tags but replace some entities ?

Comment: "I added space within the tags and entities so one can see them" — Why didn't you just use the code button in the question editor?

Comment: You should refer formatting tips.

Comment: As dirty workaround... Instead changing whole tags change only `<`, `>` to `{opening}`, `{closing}` then change it back to `<`,`>`

Comment: but I need to detect "<b>" (do not replace HTML tags) vs. "1 < 2" (do replace lt sign)